Difference between combining vs individually calling verifyNoMoreInteractions for each mock
I went through the Mockito documentation and searched Google but did not find anything.
Is there a difference between calling
 verifyNoMoreInteractions(repositoryOneMock, repositoryTwoMock, repositoryThreeMock);

vs
verifyNoMoreInteractions(repositoryOneMock);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(repositoryTwoMock);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(repositoryThreeMock);

Arguably one would think that passing the mocked objects as a list means that we're verifying there's no collective interactions between these objects, vs if we checked each one individually to see if they had any other interactions with other objects outside of the specified three.
Is calling them separately better/best practice if it (maybe?) means more granularity?

There is no difference: the code blocks in your question are equivalent. As in the Javadoc, emphasis mine:

Checks if any of given mocks has any unverified interaction.

That's exactly what it does: As in MockitoCore.verifyNoMoreInteractions(...) invoked in Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(...), the method simply invokes the check on each of the parameter objects in sequence without filtering or otherwise using the parameter array. (Do note that the behavior depends on Strictness settings, which can be affected by the way that your test is configured to invoke Mockito's runner or extension.)
Your question alludes to "there's no collective interactions between these objects", but you should only be passing mocks into verifyNoMoreInteractions(...), and it'd be unusual for those mocks to invoke one another. (Yes, they could be spies, but it'd still be somewhat unusual given their role.) Furthermore, Mockito can't tell where these mocks are invoked: as in the Javadoc linked above, the unexpected interactions might be in a setUp or @BeforeEach method.
You can choose one format or the other as a matter of style, but the behavior will not be different, and there isn't a meaningful advantage to either over the other.
